# Feeling devastated after overhearing my team manager is unhappy with my performance

Tags: offices

I am a 4 year experienced developer. I have been working in a company for a year now. I have always come early in office before my other senior peers and maintained a very good attendance. I also have done everything that was told to do. Quite a few complex problems of other people arose but I solved them too. I truly believed that I was leaving a good impression on them.

Now today when I was leaving the office, I overheard my manager saying something which devastated me. He was telling my team leader that he wasn't happy with my performance.

Many people just gossip and have fun the whole day. And here I was working and toiling hard the whole day.

My question is:  How can I make myself noticed, get ahead, and get promotions that I deserve?  What are some pointers or tactics I can use.

Comment: The way this is asked is impossible to answer. Every company, every manager, is going to be different. Have you ever had a performance appraisal with this manager? You need to find out why what he really thinks of your performance and why.

Comment: Are you completing all of your tasks on time?

Comment: @sf02 Yes. I have experience so I have a rough idea how much time should a task take

Comment: Have you received feedback about your work from other people? Maybe your peers?

Comment: @newguy Yes. Some of them were very happy that I solved their problems.

Comment: If you're confident about yourself then you don't need to fear if someone doesn't acknowledges your hard work and talent it's their loss not yours.

Comment: I just think that there is an different motive behind this. So sad that things like this happens.

Comment: @WebInsight It's great if you are able to help your coworkers, but normally if your boss says he isn't happy with your performance it indicates that there is a problem with the work he is assigning to you.  Remember, your boss is your primary customer.

Comment: @WebInsight it could simply be that your manager is unaware of your habits.  see my answer below.  pick up the book regardless. it's great (and no, I have no interest in the book at all, just found it helped me)

Comment: @newguy You are right certainly but the yearly salary increment was around the corner I actually needed a good increment for some life problems. So I was trying hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a book titled:

**Brag! : The Art of Tooting Your Own Horn Without Blowing It**

The point is that you can be busting your butt all day, but if nobody knows about it, you may as well be a slacker.  This is not about kissing butt, or being servile to the point of obsequiousness, it is about letting people know about the good work you are doing.

**The name of the game is CAR, Challenge, action result**

When you promote yourself to others, you need to remember those three words.  Talk about a challenge, the action you took, and the results you got.

Any time you bump into your manager, or anyone else, you can attack it this way.\

> Wow, things were hectic there last night!  In the middle of the shift, the widget process broke down, and we were going to get way behind.  I managed to shoehorn in some quick changes to get things back up, so we didn't miss any deadlines, then I went back, found the problem, and put in a permanent fix.  Just thought you should know about what happened.  No worries though, it's handled.

See, that's not an empty boast, it contains useful information, but gets your efforts out there for all to see.

Too many people in the tech field think that if they slave away, they'll be noticed.  The sad truth is that without a bit of self-promotion, nobody will know.  You're like an airplane pilot, nobody notices when  you're doing your job, only when you screw up.

That's why you need to manage expectations, let superiors know that problems are coming, and what you are doing about them.

Comment: Ok I will certainly read this book and hopefully get something back from my hard work. Thanks Richard

Comment: @WebInsight please do.  I had to learn the hard way, and was passed over, just as you are being now.  It will definitely open your eyes about things.  GOOD LUCK!

Comment: It might be a cultural thing. In my culture, the example you included would actually be seen as bragging and nobody likes people who do that.

Comment: @BigMadAndy which is why I recommend the book, the author is much better than I am.

Comment: @BigMadAndy btw, an example isn't a script.

Comment: @RichardU, actually an example is expected to be representative of that you mean. So yes, it's a possible script.

Answer (score 7):

You have been measuring your performance by the wrong metrics, namely:

- Butts in seats
- Solving other people's problems.

The thing your manager pays you for is to solve the problems **they** give you. That is the one core metric that you are being measured against. If you are failing this, the rest of your efforts to make a good impression don't matter.

> Many people just gossip and have fun the whole day.

If they are performing the tasks asked of them by their manager, then they are free to do so. If they are not, that is not your problem.

> How can I make myself noticed, get ahead, and get promotions that I deserve? What are some pointers or tactics I can use.

First off, get to a point where you actually deserve the promotion.

Prioritise work set by your manager ahead of everything else. That includes other people's work or ruts that they are in if it'll take more than 5 minutes. Make sure you are dotting every I and crossing every T. Do your work as you were trained to, stick to deadlines and make sure your output is good for its intended purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your insight.  Manager's work should be the most prioritised

Comment: If getting promoted is your goal, you should also let that be known to your manager and work with them to figure out what you need to do to get there. Unless you have a plan in place to stretch your skills to earn a promotion, your boss is only going to assign you work for your current level. If you want to prove you can work at a higher level, you need to make sure your boss gives you work that lets you prove yourself.

Comment: Webinsight: Not just highest priority, but sole priority.

Comment: The OP could use the promotion objective to start an informal performance conversation with the OP's manager. Ask for a one-on-one to discuss career prospects, raise promotion objective, and ask "What should I do to improve my  promotion prospects?".

Comment: @gnasher729 Sole priority is exaggerating. There's a reason why Agile uses ranked priority lists.